# Android app on Samsung incorrectly reads MiFare card via NFC

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, samsung

An Android mobile application needs to read mifare card via NFC and send this data to backend app.

However, for some users, the app is sending incorrect data (I noticed this from the backend logs), and seems to be happening only for Samsung cell phones.

Read value sent to backend is "10b2" (or "10b0") instead of correct value of 32 bytes.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Here is the snippet of data:

```
...
...
"readBlocks": [{
            "block": 16,
            "data": "10b2" // <=== incorrect data
        }, {
            "block": 17,
            "data": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        }, {
            "block": 18,
            "data": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        }, {
            "block": 28,
            "data": "45d312341234123412340040000098e9"
        }, {
            "block": 29,
            "data": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        }, {
            "block": 30,
            "data": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
        }, {
            "block": 32,
            "data": "45db12341234123412341234e8099800"
        }, {
            "block": 33,
            "data": "5393123412341234123412340481f0be"
        }, {
            "block": 34,
            "data": "539312341234123412342b2e0481f0be"
        }
```